# Bootcamp - can't save Windows support software, not enough space on available disk

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, partition

So I keep getting the above error at the following step,

1. Downloading windows support software - OK
2. Partitioning disk - OK
3. Copying windows files - OK
4. Saving windows support software - ERROR

I have tons of free space on my SSD (MBP mid-2015) and I'm allocating 140GB for Bootcamp partition.

Below is the output of diskutil list,

```
roberts-mbp:~ robertdunbar$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            65.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                522.7 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

The output of fsck_apfs -s -o -y /dev/rdisk1 is as follows,

```
roberts-mbp:~ robertdunbar$ sudo fsck_apfs -n -l /dev/rdisk1
Password:
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.250.134) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.250.134).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume Preboot was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.250.134).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume Recovery was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.250.134).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume VM was formatted by newfs_apfs (748.1.46) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.250.134).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
** Verifying allocated space.
** The volume /dev/rdisk1 appears to be OK.
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: The Boot Camp Assistant creates a temporary partition (OSXRESERVED) and copies the files to this partition. I suppose one could execute the `diskutil list` command while the Boot Camp Assistant is coping the Windows files. This would get the size of this partition. You could also just download the Windows Support Software to get the size. Finally, you could mount the Windows ISO file and determine the size of the files. Do the math and see if there is a space issue.

Comment: Did the error message say the following? **Your bootable USB drive could not be created** There is not enough space available on the disk.

Comment: Problem solved. There is a bug with the October Windows 10 ISO and BCA in the latest version of Mojave (10.14.4). The April Windows 10 ISO installs correctly. Thanks.