# Bootcamp error not enough space available on the disk

Tags: bootcamp, windows, ssd

I have a problem when trying to install Windows on my MacBook Pro 2015 using Bootcamp, I am using MacOS Mojave 10.14. I have replaced the original SSD for a different one, bigger M.2 NVMe PCI-e SSD fitted with adapter. Although everything seems to work just fine, Bootcamp seems to have troubles with the partitioning. When I run Bootcamp assistant and try to install Windows, the support software can not be saved to the disk. This is the error message I get:
[image: "The Windows support software could not be saved to the selected drive. There is not enough space available on the disk."]
Even though I have split my 1TB SSD in half. (512GB for Windows)
I have turned Time Machine off, made sure there was only 1 volume on the disk before installation...
I even tried to install Windows using USB, which almost worked, but crashed several times right before the installation finished. I have tried several ISO files. Nothing worked.
Is the main problem the replaced SSD or can there be a different problem?

Comment: Have you tried just downloading the Windows Support Software? What version of Windows are trying to install? Do you put the put Windows Support Software on the same USB as the Windows files from the ISO?

Comment: Spent a day dealing with the exact same issue. Haven't verified it, but the issue may be with the October update. Try installing the April update. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356201/bootcamp-cant-save-windows-support-software-not-enough-space-on-available-di

Comment: @Serdnad: What is the model/year of your Mac. The 2014 and older Macs use a FAT32 formatted flash drive to install Windows 10. This causes problems when using  the October 2018 update ISO. However, the 2015 and new Macs use an internal temporary ExFAT formatted partition and therefore do not have the same problems.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have tried downloading windows support software, I am trying to install Windows 10 Home - April or October 2018 version - it does not matter. I put the files to the same USB.

Comment: @Serdnad I tried installing the April update today and it ALSO worked. Boot Camp worked fine, but after windows installation (in the phase of "Getting ready") it "ran into a problem" and needed restart. So I didn't manage to install Windows that way...

Comment: @DavidAnderson I do remember reading that. My model is the Mid 2015 Retina MBP 15", and as you said, I did the install without a USB (using the April update). Though woodenowl also has a 2015 MBP, so not sure why he's going the USB route.